# Java Why is converting a long (64) to float (32) considered widening?

Tags: java, promotions

**As it states from oracle**

*Reference from* [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Widening Primitive Conversion
19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:

1. byte to short, int, long, float, or double
2. short to int, long, float, or double
3. char to int, long, float, or double
4. int to long, float, or double
5. **long to float or double**?
6. float to double

If a float has 32 bits and a long has 64 how is that considered widening? Shouldn't this be considered narrowing?

Comment: i think its related with precision. I can only think about that :)

Comment: I didn't understand your question : If a long has 32 bits and a long has 64 how is that considered widening? Shouldn't this be considered narrowing? The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer in java. please refer to the following link :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: You said "*If a long has 32 bits and a long has 64*"... make your mind up

Comment: Sorry I had a typo. See the revised question

Comment: Most valuable question. Indirectly I got a solution for a long running issue. Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The range of values that can be represented by a `float` or `double` is much larger than the range that can be represented by a `long`. Although one might lose significant digits when converting from a `long` to a `float`, it is still a "widening" operation because the range is wider.

From the [Java Language Specification, §5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long value to double, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode (§4.2.4).

Note that a `double` can exactly represent every possible `int` value.

Comment: @Mrshll187 - Actually, a `float` is 32 bits, of which 8 are for the exponent. There are only 24 bits available to represent the mantissa. I don't know what "I can be up to 64 bits" would mean. A float can represent some of the numbers in the range 1.40129846432481707e-45 to 3.40282346638528860e+38 (as well as a few special values like NaN and ±infinity). A `long` can represent all numbers in the range -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807. You can think of each type name as the name of a subset of numbers. The subsets overlap, but each subset has elements not in the other.

Comment: Thank You Ted! I was having a very hard time grasping this as I was thinking in terms of bits.

Answer (score 5):

It is considered widening because the numbers that can be represented by a float is larger than numbers that can represented by long. Just because float uses 32 bit precision does not mean the numbers it can represent are limited to 2^32.

For instance the float `(float)Long.MAX_VALUE+(float)Long.MAX_VALUE` is larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`, even though the float has less precision that the long.

Answer (score 3):

It's considered widening because `float` and `double` can represent larger values than `long`. You may lose precision, but it will be possible to represent the value (at least approximately).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the matter in simple terms, it is about how **data has been represented**  by original designers.

ideally bit depth of long(64) is larger than float(32). But float data has represented using [scientific notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)
which allows to represent considerably much larger range

Ex: 300[original number] : 3×102 [scientific representation]

---

Long : -2^63 to 2^63-1

Float : (-3.4)*10^38 to (3.4)*10^38

*Notice the Long(power of two) Vs Float(power of ten) representational difference here which allow float to have higher range*

hope this is helpful